# clojure idiomatic name for impure function

Tags: clojure, coding-style, naming-conventions

In Clojure, functions that modify their input conventionally end with an `!` to warn the user. I even extended this: two `!!` means that the function has a side effect that modifies something that was *not* put in (i.e. global states that must persist across user-GUI interactions).

What is the convention for a function that is impure in that it *uses* an external state, such as file *loading*, etc?

Comment: Many impure functions don't end in `!`. The more predictable pattern is that operations that specifically are not safe inside a transaction end in `!`. See for example `alter-var-root` (very impure, no `!`, safe in transactions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such convention. Impurity should be apparent from the functions name or docstring or purpose.

Examples:

`get-settings-from-file`

`(get-settings :source :file)`

`load-configuration`

`import-data`

Answer (score 0):

[Metatdata](https://clojure.org/reference/metadata) is a useful way to annotate functions that are impure. By convention, I've been labeling functions with an `^:impure` marker thusly:

```clj
(defn ^:impure blech []
  (mq/publish ...)
  (spit ...)
  (time/now ...)
  (http/request ...)
  (db/write-something ...))
```

I tend to only do this to bottom-layer functions. So if `bar` calls `blech`, it can be inferred that `bar` is also impure, and I don't have to pollute every impure function this way.

With this metadata in place, other tools (editors, reports, etc) can assist by indicating that a given function appears to have no impurities all the way down, and you can then see that it's a strong candidate for a unit test (vs those that will need mocking). You can also perform analytics to indicate how much of your code base is trending toward pure.